# How can I update a field in every document in Firebase Firestore from Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm making an app with a pretend stock market and I need to update a certain field (an array (prices) in an object (stock) of a document (the company). I need to have a random value between the last price - 2 and the last price + 2 and add that to the prices array for every company (document).

How would I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Also any advice to simplify this question would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

Query the entire collection, iterate each document, and foreach document:

1. Read the contents of the array.
2. Update the contents of document with the new values you want it to have.

Comment: How do I get the arrays and update them? Sorry I’m very new to this.